# How to configure LFS for multilib support?

Tags: 64bit, lfs, 32bit, compatibility

I managed to install FLS pure 64-bit, but i want to "upgrade it" so it supports 32-bit also. I don't want to build LFS from ground up again. Is there a way to install multilib support on an already built 64-bit version LFS?

Comment: For future reference, the official multilib is [here](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/~thomas/multilib/index.html). This is what I always build from the start. There isn't an official "add-on" guide that I'm aware of but someone has probably attempted it somewhere. You might search/ask the LFS mailing list. I would think you could carefully work your way through the multilib book, since it now uses `lib` for 64-bit, `lib32` for 32-bit and `libx32` for x32 ABI (the old way put 32-bit in `lib`). Honestly though, if you haven't build (m)any BLFS packages, I would start over, that's just me. GL

Comment: PS. **If** you only want multilib for VirtualBox (like I did way back when), then I *think* it's only required to build the 32-bit guest additions... Anyway, I switched to `qemu` for other reasons and it's great after I got over the learning curve.